# I need to make a "perfect tree"-like from pandas dataframe based on values in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, tree, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   name1 name2  name3 
0    1     2     3
1    1     2     1
2    1     3     4
```

How can I transform it to like this:

```
   name1 name2  name3 
0    1     2     1
0    1     2     3
0    1     2     4
2    1     3     1
2    1     3     3
2    1     3     4
```

If we look at tree representation:

```
                       1
                      /  \
                     /    \
                    /      \
                   /        \
                  2          3   
                 /|\        /|\
                / | \      / | \
               1  3  4    1  3  4
```

I have a solution but it's very long and primitive, all about append and repeat,
my question is, is there a built-in function that can do what I'm asking, or maybe a suggestion for a short code solution?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import product
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
         product(*(set(s) for _,s in df.iteritems())),
         columns=df.columns
       )

print(df2)
```

Alternative with a cross `merge`:

```
df2 = (df[['name1', 'name2']].drop_duplicates()
       .merge(df[['name3']].drop_duplicates(), how='cross')
      )
```

output:

```
   name1  name2  name3
0      1      2      1
1      1      2      3
2      1      2      4
3      1      3      1
4      1      3      3
5      1      3      4
```

Comment: Your first answer was the one I needed, it gives all the possibilities.
Your second answer gives all the possibilities based on the last column only
try :
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2022,2023],'b':[3,4],'c':['CAL','CAL'],'d':[3,4]})

If we look at column 'a' = 2023 I expected to see all possibilities for example where column 'b' = 3